# Spark + MySQL: no spark.read

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark

I just downloaded Spark 2.2 from the [website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), and created a simple project with the example from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases).

The code is this:

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.spark


object MysqlTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val jdbcDF = spark.read
                      .format("jdbc")
                      .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hap")
                      .option("dbtable", "hap.users")
                      .option("user", "***")
                      .option("password", "***")
                      .load()

  }

}
```

The problem is that apparently **`spark.read` does not exist**.

I guess the Spark API's documentation is not up to date and the examples do not work. I would appreciate a working example.

Comment: I don't know the 2.2 API but I'm pretty sure **"import org.apache.spark"** does not do what you need. You have to initialize a spark session

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Yo bro")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: The example was super misleading, this seems to work

Comment: Dunno if you are forced to code in Java, but Scala is more user friendly. Moreover you can use Jupyter with a kernel like spylon-kernel (what I use) for discovering Spark. There is Apache Toree (even though it's popular, I find spylon-kernel much better). I really enjoy coding in Spark and discovering the language with Jupyter

Answer (score 0):

The docs should be correct, but you skipped over the strt where the initialization is explained.https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession

The convention whith spark docs is the `spark` is a `SparkSession` instance, so that needs to be created first.  You do this with the `SparkSessionBuilder`.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()

 // For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
 import spark.implicits._
```